# set trustworthy on - is it a bad practice? if so any alternatives?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a group of users "readers" that have only dbreader on "mydatabase".
I have a stored procedure "sp" that:

---

1 - updates data within "mydatabase",

2 - truncate tables within database "mydatabase" - and this is done using dynamic sql because we don't know the names of the tables that need to be truncated

3 -  update records inside tables in "mydatabse2"

4 - insert records inside tables in "mydatabse3"

---

The way I sorted this problem out is:

1 - I set the db owner of all these 3 databases to sa

2 - I changed the stored procedure "sp" to be EXECUTE AS OWNER

3 - I set all these 3 databases as TRUSTWORTHY ON

---

All is running fine.

My concern and hence this question here is:

Is there any serious security gap that is left open by using TRUSTWORHY ON?

I could not find anything serious, so I am leaving this ON.

Unless someone here can remind me of something that maybe I missed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TRUSTWORTHY` option, when set for a particular database, allows code from that database to access external objects outside of it (such as other databases, for example).

Since the only place where you have any code that needs external access is `mydatabase`, you can safely turn this option off for the remaining two.

The option itself isn't particularly dangerous; after all, before it first appeared in SQL Server 2005, everything was accessible straight away, as long as you had sufficient permissions. And I can't recall any particular whining on the topic in question from that era. Just make sure you keep the amount of `db_owner` members reasonably small, that's usually enough.

Comment: There are potential privilege escalation issues - see http://akawn.com/blog/2012/10/a-warning-about-the-trustworthy-database-option/